# Android darken background

Tags: java, android, toolbar, statusbar

Does anyone know how to programmatically darken a `View's` background like `alertDialog` or `NavigationDrawer` doing it? I need the background overlaps the `ToolBar` (1) and `StatusBar`, but the icons for the `StatusBar` should be visible(2). In my case it should not be a `dialog`. For example, I had to darken the background around the `Button` or `CustomView`.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLc4o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this question for a long time, but finally I found a solution.

I researched code "DialogPlus" library and find out what is the key point.

[orhanobut/dialogplus](https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus)

**`getWindow().getDecorView();`**

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View background = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame, null);
        final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.in);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                decorView.addView(background);
                background.startAnimation(a);
            }
        });
```

background resoource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="0.5"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```